# Post data without image using Afnetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, afnetworking

I want to upload user information to the server. It contains user avatar and user profile data. Now the problem is that user does not upload the avatar always so i want to filter the image if user does not upload it so can anyone help me on this?

Right now i am uploading image using this code and it works fine but i want to upload even when the user does not upload the image

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL]];
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [manager POST:url parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"file" fileName:@"image.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success %@", responseObject);
        [Util showAlertDialog: NSLocalizedString(@"Success", nil):NSLocalizedString(@"Upload Successful", nil)];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure %@, %@", error, operation.responseString);
        [ Util showAlertDialog: NSLocalizedString(@"Failed", nil):NSLocalizedString(@"Upload Failed, Please try again", nil)];
    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i solved it myself by sending empty NSData

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL]];
        NSData *imageData;
        CGImageRef cgref = [image CGImage];
        CIImage *cim = [image CIImage];

        if (cim == nil && cgref == NULL)
        {
            imageData = [[NSData alloc] init];
        }else{
            imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        }

        [manager POST:url parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"file" fileName:@"image.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success %@", responseObject);
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:view animated:YES];
        [Util showAlertDialog: NSLocalizedString(@"Success", nil):NSLocalizedString(@"Upload Successful", nil)];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure %@, %@", error, operation.responseString);
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:view animated:YES];
        [ Util showAlertDialog: NSLocalizedString(@"Failed", nil):NSLocalizedString(@"Upload Failed, Please try again", nil)];
    }];
```